# How disable RefreshAll button in excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to hide the button `Refresh All` from the ribbon of Excel 2013 using VBA. It looks complicated. I tried to find code example.

Comment: Are you able to [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1002989/edit) your question with what you have tried so far?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043318/hide-individual-custom-ribbon-buttons